# Error while raising fault from the DUT to Onvif Device test tool in the test case

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client, onvif, python-onvif

**Error while raising fault from the DUT in the test case.**
   ==========================================================

> In the test case EventProperties>RealTimePullPointNotification
>   Interface>EVENT-3-1-17-v14.12 REAL TIME PULL POINT
>   SUBSCRIPTION-INVALID MESSAGE CONTENT FILTER the DUT sends fault
>   message to client.
>
> While validating the fault in the client(Onvif
>   Device Test Tool Ver 6.12) I am getting the error No Action element
>   from namespace Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing).
>
> I set the wsa:Action Element to http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault then also i am getting
>   the above error.

## **The output from onvif device test tool is as below:**

```
EVENT-3-1-17-v14.12 REALTIME PULLPOINT SUBSCRIPTION - INVALID MESSAGE CONTENT FILTER

STEP 4 - Create Pull Point Subscription - negative test
StepStart: 2019-11-13T17:18:31.6582116Z
Transmit done
Receive done
SOAP fault returned
Code: Sender
Reason: InvalidMessageContentExpression
Validate fault...
*No Action element from namespace Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing). Expected element with value: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault.*
STEP FAILED
TEST FAILED
```

**My XML which sends error from DUT to client is as below:**
  ========================================================

```
*std::string soapFault =
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">"
"<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" >"
"<wsa:MessageID>"
"urn:uuid:c9517d6a-44e7-427a-a1f4-6902eb52a979"
"</wsa:MessageID>"
"<wsa:ReplyTo SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">"
"<wsa:Address>http://192.168.0.95:8082/onvif</wsa:Address>"
"</wsa:ReplyTo>"
"<wsa:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://192.168.0.95:8082/onvif/event_service</wsa:To>"
"<wsa:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault"</wsa:Action>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Header>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Fault>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Code>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Subcode>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:InvalidArgVal</SOAP-ENV:Value>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Subcode>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:InvalidMessageContentExpression</SOAP-ENV:Value>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Subcode>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Subcode>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Code>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Reason>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en"/>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Reason>"
"<SOAP-ENVetail>"
"</SOAP-ENVetail>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Fault>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";*
```

Answer (score 0):

From §9.9 of the [ONVIF Core Specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification.pdf):

> **9.9   SOAP Fault Messages**
>
> If a device encounters a failure while processing [WS-BaseNotification] messages from either a client or
>   Subscription Manager, then the device shall generate a SOAP 1.2 fault
>   message.All SOAP 1.2 fault messages shall be generated according to
>   [WS-BaseNotification] and [WS-Topics]  specifications  with  one 
>   exception;
>
> All  faults  shall  use  the  following  URI  for  the 
>   WS-Addressing [action] Message Addressing
>   Property::
>
> `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault`
>
> Furthermore
>   the error should be sent as a SOAP receiver fault (env:Receiver), i.e.
>   the HTTP error code shall be 500.

Comment: I tried to send soap 1.2 receiver fault. from DUT I am still getting the same error "No Action element from namespace Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing). Expected element with value:    http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault."